# Which iOS setting is 200% system font size?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to satisfy WCAG accessibility requirements for iOS, which say mobile device UI should scale well up to 200%, but no-where online can I find which setting on the unlabeled, sliding bar is actually 200%.

I thought I would be clever and use VO on the sliding scale to get it to read out to me what the font size is, but it's just on a scale of 0-100%, even if you turn on larger font sizes, so it's actually meaningless.

[image: images of iOS system font size settings]

Comment: As Gnasher729 says, don't get hung up on font sizes.  Turn on "Larger accessibility sizes" and set the slider to maximum and try and support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle scaling, I wrote a class that will return a font with the right size, given the font size it should have at a normal screen, taking into account scaling, and limiting to some limit. Then I’d run the code and manually set the limits for font sizes so it “works” whatever size the use chooses.

You can also use automatic font adjustments so a smaller font size will be used to make things fit.

So I don’t care about “200%”, I make it work whatever the user chooses. In extreme case I switch to landscape if there is no way to make a view fit in portrait. And vertical scrolling is always allowed if the view doesn’t fit otherwise.

Comment: iOS makes this trivial by using `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:)`. No need for special handling. Use styles and iOS will give you the correct font based on the user's settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think gnasher729 has the correct answer: dont care about the exact percentage, just make it work for the largest size.

But I did eventually find the exact percentage font size each notch on the slider corresponds to (shown in the image). Turns out, there is no exact 200% scaling value on the slider, so the closest ones are the 9th and 10th spot on the slider, once large a11y sizes are turned on.
[image]

Comment: What's the source for these percentages?